# Magento 2: Data Migration errors using magento 2 data migration tools

Tags: magento2, database, error, ce-1.9.2.1, magento2-migration-tool

I am migrate data magento version 1.9.2.1 to version 2.
Migrate Setting are successfully done. Migrate Data are run and display error like

```
[PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-Mi  
  gration_Default' for key 'EAV_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ENTITY_TYPE_ID_ATTRIBUTE_SET_NA  
  ME'
```

and in  migration.log file at delta migrate,

```
[2015-12-24 06:05:03][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2015-12-24 06:05:03][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2015-12-24 06:05:03][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Map Step]: started
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Map Step]: started
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: rating_option_vote
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: rating_option_vote_aggregated
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: rating_store
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_event
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: report_viewed_product_index
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: review
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: review_detail
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: review_entity_summary
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: review_store
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoice
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoice_comment
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoice_item
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_address
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_item
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_payment
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_status_history
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_address
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_item
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_item_option
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_payment
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: quote_shipping_rate
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipment
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipment_item
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipment_track
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoiced_aggregated
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoiced_aggregated_order
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_aggregated_created
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_aggregated_updated
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_status_state
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipping_aggregated
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipping_aggregated_order
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule_coupon
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule_coupon_usage
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule_customer
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule_customer_group
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule_product_attribute
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: salesrule_website
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: shipping_tablerate
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sitemap
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: tax_calculation
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: tax_calculation_rule
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: tax_class
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: wishlist
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: Log Step]: started
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: Log Step]: started
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: customer_visitor
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: OrderGrids Step]: started
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_order_grid
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_invoice_grid
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch of entities in the document: sales_shipment_grid
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][INFO][mode: delta][stage: delta delivering][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: started
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch in last increment id of order entity
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch in last increment id of invoice entity
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch in last increment id of creditmemo entity
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Mismatch in last increment id of shipment entity
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][WARNING]: Volume Check failed
[2015-12-24 06:05:04][INFO][mode: delta][stage: volume check][step: SalesIncrement Step]: Migration completed successfully
```

Catalog,Customer,CMS,Category all data are available from magento 1 to magento 2 but Review, Sales Related Data are not appear in migrate data.
How to do for sales order and review  related data in migration?

Comment: please run the command with `-vvv` option for more details (`bin/magento migrate:data /path/to/config.xml -vvv`)

Comment: mismatch of entities warnings still occur.Not solved issue.

Comment: no additional information about this error with `-vvv`?

Answer (score 2):

this error is of duplication. If you see in your M1 database then `Default` attribute set will be duplicated in `eav_attribute_set` table.
So, the solution for this is delete all `Default` attribute set from your M1 db and then start your migration to new blank fresh Magento2 db.

I hope it would help. :-)